# C# select data from DataTable into pre-defined columns

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, adapter

I have DataGridView with predefined columns: id, name, phone.

In SQL Server database, I have a `Users` table with these columns:

```
user_id, user_name, user_phone
```

Select data from `Users` table :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM users", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
ad.Fill(dt);

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

This code works fine and shows all rows. But the main problem is DataTable also adds the `Users` table columns to the DataGridView.

DataGridView output:

```
id | name | phone | user_id | user_name | user_phone
```

How to add rows from DataTable to specific pre-defined columns?

And another question is how to prevent DataTable to add SQL Server table columns to DataGridView?

Thank you.

Comment: Change your query : "SELECT id as ID, name as PERSON, phone , user_id as UID, user_name as UNAME, user_phone FROM users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the columns to your `DataGridView` in the designer and set the `DataPropertyName` property of each column to the data source column name you want it to bind to. In code, set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `False` before setting the `DataSource`.